# Testing with pytest: import that works on GitLab doesn't work in VS Code (and vice versa)

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, gitlab, pipeline

TL;DR: How can I set up my GitLab test pipeline so that the tests also run locally on VS Code?

I'm very new to GitLab pipelines, so please forgive me if the question is amateurish. I have a GitLab repo set up online, and I'm using VS Code to develop locally. I've created a new pipeline, I want to make sure all my unit tests (written with PyTest) run anytime I make a commit.

The issue is, that even though I use the same `setup.py` file for both places (obviously), I can't get both VS Code testing and the GitLab pipeline test to work at the same time. The issue is, I'm doing an import for my tests, and if I import like

```
...
from external_workforce import misc_tools
# I want to test functions in this misc_tools module
...
```

Then it works on GitLab, but not on VS Code, as VS Code gives an error when I'm doing test discovery, namely: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'external_workforce'`. However, this works on GitLab. But if I import (in my `test_tools.py` file, see location below) like this:

```
...
from hr_datapool.external_workforce import misc_tools 
...
```

It works in VS Code, but now GitLab is doing a crazy on me saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hr_datapool'`.

I think the relevant info might be the following, please ask for more if more info is needed!

My file structure is:

```
.
|__ requirements.txt
    setup.py
    hr_datapool
    |__ external_workforce
        |__ __init__.py
            misc_tools.py
            tests
            |__ test_tools.py
        |__ other_module
            ...
```

In my pipeline editor (the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file) I have:

```
image: python:3.9.7

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python --version  # For debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
  script:
    - pytest --pyargs hr_datapool #- python setup.py test

run:
  script:
    - python setup.py bdist_wheel
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*.whl
```

And finally, my `setup.py` is:

```
import re
from unittest import removeResult
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()
    for req in ['wheel', 'bar']:
        requirements.append(req)
    
setup(
   name='hr-datapool',
   version='0.1',
   ...
   packages=find_packages(), 
   install_requires=requirements,
)
```

Basically, the question is: How can I set up my GitLab test pipeline so that the tests also run locally on VS Code? Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Adding the full trace coming from VS Code:

```
> conda run -n base --no-capture-output --live-stream python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir "." -s --cache-clear hr_datapool
cwd: .
[ERROR 2022-2-23 9:2:4.500]: Error discovering pytest tests:
 [r [Error]: ============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/myuser/Documents/myfolder
plugins: anyio-2.2.0
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____ ERROR collecting hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py ______
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/myuser/Documents/myfolder/hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py:2: in <module>
    from external_workforce import misc_tools
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'external_workforce'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR hr_datapool/external_workforce/tests/test_tools.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
===================== no tests collected, 1 error in 0.08s =====================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py", line 26, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
  File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/pytest/_discovery.py", line 44, in discover
    raise Exception("pytest discovery failed (exit code {})".format(ec))
Exception: pytest discovery failed (exit code 2)
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', '/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py', '/Users/A111086670/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py', 'discover', 'pytest', '--', '--rootdir', '/Users/myuser/Documents/myfolder', '-s', '--cache-clear', 'hr_datapool']' command failed.  (See above for error)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/out/client/extension.js:32:39235)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` caused the problem.

**As** `external_workforce` parent folder path -> the path of `hr_datapool` in the `PYTHONPATH` when you are using GitLab. **While** `hr_datapool` parent folder path in the `PYTHONPATH` when you are using VSCode.

Are you running the test in the terminal on the VSCode? And have you added this in the settings.json file?

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder};"
  },
```

Then you can execute `pytest` in the terminal on the VSCode. But you have not configured this in GitLab instead of adding `hr-datapool`( `- pytest --pyargs hr_datapool` or `setup( name='hr-datapool',`), so you will get the error message.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. `external_workforce`'s parent folder is `hr_datapool` in both cases. Also, I'm on MacOS, is the setting still called `...env.windows`? I'm trying to run the tests from VS Code's testing function (bottom left icon in the left pane), I think that eventually that does uses the VS Code terminal. But as an interpreter in VS Code I'm using the conda python installation, and I also install to the conda environment with `setup.py`.

Comment: @lte__ Sorry for that, it's the `osx`. Could you execute `pprint(sys.path)`, I think you will get the different result of `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: If I use the VS Code terminal to run python and print `sys.path`, it looks like it's trying to use Python 2.7?? But I selected the conda version via cmd-shift-P and the "Select interpreter". Also, adding `"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder};"},` to the settings json didn't solve it.

Comment: @lte__ Yes, that's the problem of `Code Runer`.

Comment: Oh it's definitely trying to use the right conda interpreter, I can tell by the path it prints for the error. I'll add the full trace to the post, just a sec.

Comment: @lte__ Could you try to create a `.env` in the root path of VSCode, and added PYTHONPATH=./hr_datapool in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243218/discussion-between-lte-and-steven-msft).